# How do I update the code of an exe file made by auto-py-to-exe

Tags: python, console, exe, auto-py-to-exe

I used auto-py-to-exe to generate a exe file for my python code that inly runs in console window. I have noticed if I try to update my code for example adding on a new print statement it won't update. How should I fix this? I looked in file that auto-py-to-exe generated to hold my exe there was just a exe file in it nothing else for me to edit my code. So how do I edit it (the original python file and automatically update the exe)?

Comment: You don't edit the .exe, you edit your original python code and then recompile it again by rerunning py-to-exe

Comment: I edit my original code but I don't want to re compile it it takes too long

Comment: You don't really have a choice. That's what compiling is

Comment: Do you know of any programs out there that can help me do that?

Comment: No, but some of the other compilers out there might be faster. You could also use a beefier PC or move the things you're changing to separate config files.

Comment: You'd typically only build a new executable when you need it (e.g. you're ready to ship a new version). Most development can take place in the Python world, without any compilation step.

Comment: So are you saying that I can test and run my original python file and develop and test it in my IDE and recompile to release updates when needed? That might be a good Idea.

Comment: Yes, of course. Building an `.exe` doesn't stop the original Python from working.